# Get part of JSON from URL with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, url

I'm trying to get only the specific value of "E_m" from this below URL with pure JavaScript but I cannot find how to make it.

URL:
https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/PVcalc?lat=45&lon=8&peakpower=1&loss=14&outputformat=json

JSON Tree:

```
"outputs": {
         "monthly": {
             "fixed": {
                 {"E_m": 80.15}}}}
```

Comment: I don't see "E_m" in the URL.

Comment: Don't ask people to visit external sites.  Include the output of the URL that you're talking about in your question.  But ... try this: `JSON.parse(whatever).outputs.monthly.fixed.E_m`